# Query in php on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I can't use my query in php when i use codeigniter.
I think that it's all ok but my code doesn't work.
What is it wrong ?

I need to cofront two parametres.

I have a table  and i need colonn3

Models:

```
    function get_colonn3($data){
        $this->db->select("table.colonn3");
        $this->db->where("table.colonn3",$data);
        return $this->db->get("table.colonn3")->result_array();
```

Controller:

```
$colonn3_exsist = $this->my_model->get_colonn3($data)

if($colonn3_exsist):
echo "ok";
endif;
```

Comment: what is the value of `$data` is your table name `table`?

Answer (score 0):

Remove table.colon3 from get(), maybe it will work

```
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe is because you're passing the table name to the where statement and it expects a column.

[CodeIgniter where documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data)

```
function get_colonn3($data) {
    $this->db->select("table.colonn3");

    $this->db->where("colonn3", $data);

    return $this->db->get("table")->result_array();
}
```

They also allow you to pass an array to the where parameters too:

```
function get_colonn3($data) {
    $this->db->select("table.colonn3");

    $this->db->where([
        "colonn3" => $data
    ]);

    return $this->db->get("table")->result_array();
}
```

CI also allows you to chain DB functions like so:

```
function get_colonn3($data) {
    $this->db->select("table.colonn3")
        ->where([
            "colonn3" => $data
        ]);

    return $this->db->get("table")->result_array();
}
```

Comment: And in controller ? How use colonn3 ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

//model

```
function get_colonn3($data){
        $this->db->select("colonn3");
        $this->db->where("colonn3",$data);
 return $this->db->get("table")->result_array();
```

//controller

```
$colonn3_exsist = $this->my_model->get_colonn3($data)
if($colonn3_exsist>0){
echo"ok";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value to `WHERE` in a wrong way. You have to pass the values in an array without passing the table name.

You have to pass the array in `WHERE` clause like this if you have more than one parameter to compare from Database:

```
function get_colonn3($para1,$para2){
  $this->db->select("table.colonn3");
  $this->db->where(['columnname1' => $para1, 'columnname2' => $para2]);
  return $this->db->get("table.colonn3")->result_array();
}
```

If you have only one parameter to compare then you can use this:

```
function get_colonn3($para1){
      $this->db->select("table.colonn3");
      $this->db->where('columnname1',$para1);
      return $this->db->get("table.colonn3")->result_array();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
 function get_colonn3($data){
   return $this->db->select("table.colonn3 as col3")->from('table')->where(['table.colonn3' => $data])->get()->row()->col3;
}
```

Controller

```
$colonn3 = $this->my_model->get_colonn3($data)

if(!empty($colonn3)):
  echo "ok"; 
endif;
```